# Error Configure VS codespace

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I am currently facing an error while configuring salesforce with VS code online

**`We encountered a JSON web token error, which is likely not an issue with Salesforce CLI. Here’s the error: refresh_token scope is required and the connected app should be installed and preauthorized.`**

I have followed the provided steps.

http://www.apexhours.com/sfdx-with-visual-studio-codespace/

Is there any step by step document available from salesforce authentic guide?

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components

Try with this trailhead module.

Comment: I am talking about VScode Online, not VScode installed

Comment: There is likely to be no official guide from Salesforce since they're working on [Code Builder](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/06/introducing-code-builder.html) which is in pilot currently and will save you the hassle of doing what you're doing now. I presume your error is from the JWT part of the link you provided? I'd [edit] your question to be more specific in what you've done and what command led to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the pilot? If you are, reach out to the pilot contact person. If not, there is no Salesforce support for this. Likely there's not a lot of MSFT support, as Code Spaces is itself still in [beta](https://docs.github.com/en/github/developing-online-with-codespaces/about-codespaces).

Once Salesforce goes live with Code Builder, there should be a lot of support and help for problems like this. But right now, folks are busy building it.